# How to get Next post ID from inside the WP_Query loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a wordpress code like below to list all posts under specific term of.

```
<?php
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'videos', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'video-categories',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $category_id
        )
    )
);
?>
<?php   $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php   if($loop) :?>
<?php   while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>

... things to do inside the loop ...

<?php   endwhile; ?>
<?php   endif;?>
<?php   wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

What I want to achieve is, I want to get the ID of Next post for each post from within INSIDE the loop. How can I do that? E.g. under loop, if current ID is 10 then I need the next post ID of post ID 10.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood the question you want to get id of next post in loop. For that:
You can use the function : [get_next_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post)

```
get_next_post()
```

Use `$wp_query->is_single = true;` inside your loop.

If you are in single.php you can do this:

```
$next_post = get_adjacent_post($in_same_cat,$excluded_categories,$previous)
```

Comment: No, as the description on wordpress codex says, it retrieves next post that is adjacent to "current post"

Comment: So?/ You need the next post adjacent to current post dont you?

Comment: Yes but from INSIDE the WP_Query loop. Did you see the code I posted?

Comment: Hmm, this may work. But I don't have $wp_query anywhere in the code.

Comment: I think you can pass is_single => true in $args

Comment: Do $wp_query->is_single = true; inside your loop. It is global variable!!

Comment: yeah I did it but its not helping at all. May be it is because this is already on a single.php page ?

Comment: Thanks but now its showing some wrong record, not the exact next record. Actually the code I have posted here is already inside the single loop. So its loop inside main loop. To stop issues, I added <?php   wp_reset_postdata();?> in the end of the loop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39717/discussion-between-sankalp-mishra-and-aslamdoctor)